# File upload with Jersey 2 and Jetty

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jersey, jetty

- Hello everyone.

I developed a webservice which runs on Jetty with a RESTful API using Jersey 2.
I later had to create a file upload method (mainly for XLS/XML files) and I tried to use Jersey 2's Multipart libraries for it.

However, as the server starts, it throws immediately a strange exception:

```
2016-09-21 01:13:13.578:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@17f62e33{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/jersey/internal/inject/ExtractorException
at org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.internal.FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.createValueFactory(FormDataParamValueFactoryProvider.java:436)
```

[.............................................]

## Jetty Server

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(API.class);
    resourceConfig.packages("the_package_where_these_classes_are");
    resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet
            = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));

    Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(jettyServer, "/");
    context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, "/*");

    try {
        jettyServer.start();
        jettyServer.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        //jettyServer.destroy(); 
        // got an IllegalStateException uncommenting this and didn't quite understand why
     }
}
```

## Endpoints/Jersey/JAX-RS

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.InputStream;


@Path("/")
public class API {

@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                           @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails) throws Exception {

    
    System.out.println(fileDetails.getFileName());
    return Response.ok().build();
}
}
```

## Application configs

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.Set;

public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();
    resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
    resources.add(API.class);

    return resources;
}
}
```

## Maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.11.v20160721</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-multipart -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Am I using some wrong dependency? Shouldn't this simple service work? I never used Multipart before, so I tried to go by several Internet sources/tutorials.

Thanks in advance!

**FIXED**

I changed the version to latest in all Jersey dependencies and it worked!

Comment: why you have jersey-media-multipart twice ?

Comment: It was my mistake pasting|

Answer (score 0):

`jersey-media-multipart` depends on `jersey-common` , add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: ravthiru, it still didn't solve the issue, it's throwing the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked like below:

```
        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(ApplicationConfig.class);
        resourceConfig.packages("com.econorma.rest");
        resourceConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);

        ServletHolder jerseyServlet  = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(resourceConfig));
```

This is ApplicationConfig class

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(MultiPartFeature.class);
        resources.add(EntryPoint.class);
        return resources;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.econorma.rest");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jersey provides examples for corresponding versions. You can add below dependency to project and by using '*Download sources*' feature of IDE you can download source code for this example.By clicking pom parent you can see all examples for same jersey version as well.Hope it helps!

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.examples</groupId>
        <artifactId>multipart-webapp</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```